# how to get custom notifications for each whatsapp contact on lumia 920

Tags: whatsapp, contacts, notifications

I know how to give each contact a different notification sound but the only sounds to choose from is the normal Windows and Nokia sounds. I know that when you want to set custom sounds to an app in whole, you can just copy the song/sound into the ringtone folder and it works but these sounds doesn't show inside whatsapp when choosing sounds for different contacts. So the question is if there is any way to get your own sounds for separate contacts inside whatsapp?

Answer (score 1):

You can set custom notifications for WhatsApp. Here is how you can can do it.

1. Open a contact's profile.
2. Click on custom notifications.

[image]

3. Turn on Custom notifications.

[image]

4. Click on *message sound* or *ringtone* to choose a custom ringtone for message and calls respectively.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom notification for an app, if it provides such facility,

WhatsApp was not providing such facility, but after WhatsApp v2.12.194.

Current Stable version of WhatsApp is :
for Windows Phone : 2.16.14
for android : 2.16.16
for iOS : 2.16.1
for symbian : 2.16.9
for Nokia S40 devices: 2.16.4
for BlackBerry: 2.16.4

> Source :
>
> - [Custom notification ver. details](http://tech.firstpost.com/news-analysis/whatsapp-app-update-custom-notifications-mark-as-unread-low-data-setting-and-more-275112.html)
> - [WhatsApp Stable Versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WhatsApp)